# Loading stock information of Japan using quantmod package in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I encounter one problem of using R/quantmod package. I can get the stock information for Korea, but I failed in getting the information for Japan:

```
getSymbols("DEXKOUS",src="FRED") #load Korea
[1] "DEXKOUS"
getSymbols("DEXJPUS",src="FRED") #load Japan   
Error as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Your comments are welcome.

---

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                                                   
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] PerformanceAnalytics_1.0.3.2 quantmod_0.3-17              TTR_0.21-0                  
 [4] xts_0.8-2                    zoo_1.7-4                    Defaults_1.1-1              
 [7] Rweibo_0.0-5                 rjson_0.2.5                  digest_0.5.1                
 [10] RCurl_1.6-6.1                bitops_1.0-4.1              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.13.1     lattice_0.19-30 tools_2.13.1
```

Comment: This works for me.  What's your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Thank you for your reminding. I add them into the question.

Answer (score 5):

The example you give in your question works fine for me too. I get a time series of the yen-dollar rate from 1971 onwards.

However, if you are looking for share price data rather than forex (you did say stock information?) then perhaps you should try the RFinanceYJ package, which extracts share price data from Yahoo! Japan.

```
require(RFinanceYJ)
sony <- quoteStockXtsData('6758.t', '2011-01-01')
tail(sony,30)
```

Comment: I guess the problem is caused my setting of language. Thank u.